# Field Validator

Tags: asp.net, html

In the code below, the submit buttion has the 'SubmitValidation' ValidationGroup.

When i change the name of the ValidationGroup in the RequiredFieldValidator (to submitValidation123), the Error Message 'Enter State Code' does not appear (as expected). However, the submit does not take place till I actually enter a value for the state code. WHY?

```
<tr>
     <td>
      <span class="requiredText">*</span> State Code (Ex. TX):
     </td>
   <td>
      <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="statecodeTxt" Width="100px"></asp:TextBox> 
      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="statecodeRFV" runat="server" 
           Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="submitValidation"
        ControlToValidate="statecodeTxt" SetFocusOnError="True"
            ErrorMessage="Enter State Code" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

---

```
<asp:Button ID="submitBtn" Text="Submit" disabled="true" 
 runat="server" ValidationGroup="submitValidation"  
 OnClick="submitBtn_Click" />
```

Comment: It does submit for me... Check your code mate.

Comment: I checked the code again. Just not able to submit till the State Code is entered.

Comment: @stackuser What do you mean "the submit does not take place till I actually enter a value for the state code"? Also, what "enables" your submit button? There is something you've left out of your question. If ValdiationGroup of button is different than ValidationGroup of a validator, that validator will not be used.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev, i think what he is trying to say is on button click it is still validating textbox when it shouldn't

Comment: @rs that is my point, and why I am seeking clarification as he is not being completely clear or including all code... Perhaps he doesn't enable the submit button until someone types in the statecode.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev - What I mean is that when the submit button is clicked, all validation must be passed - which includes the Required Field Validation - only then the form is submitted. Even though I changed the name of the validationgroup for the state code, it still requires me to enter it. As soon as I enter the state code and press Submit, it works fine.

Comment: @stackuser can you please include the code that *doesn't* work instead of code that you aren't using? The code that you have in your question is working as expected. And also please clarify what is enabling that submit button. Are you setting in validationgroups in the code-behind?

Answer (score 0):

Try remove or make false the 
    SetFocusOnError="True"